# Magento 1.8 if click Ship to different address Shipping information fields must be empty

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, shipping-methods, shipping-address

When i click `Ship to different address` in check out page shipping information all the `textbox` must be empty.

For example if i click  `Ship to different address` radio button, it takes default address. 
[image]

I need all the fields must be empty

[image]

Comment: Try to add this `onclick="this.form.reset();"` on that button and check. Or you can go through each fields after onclick and set those to ' '. Like that. Or you can go to the phtml file and remove those values magento added there. Its simple.

Comment: Thank you @KingshukDeb you mean edit `app\design\frontend\themename\default\template\checkout\multishipping\addresses.phtml` file right

Comment: You can check the filename after enabling `template path hints` from admin panel. However not sure if thats the correct file. To enable template path hints in magento check this. Dont forget to select your store there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint

Comment: Oh thank you i got the path it is  in`frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml
`

Comment: Not sure. Seems not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml` 
commend the firstname values like this

```
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
```

and same as `lastname` commend `lastname` also.

And then go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

commend all feild values `address1`,`address2`,`city`, `state`, `country`, `zipcode`, `phone`.